# add a number for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, prepend

Hi I'd like some advice with what I'm trying to achieve.

I currently have this:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="thumbnail_1.jpg" />
</div>
```

For each `.thumbnail` I would like to prepend an index number with a span. Achieving this:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<span class="index">001</span>
<img src="thumbnail_1.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="thumbnail">
<span class="index">002</span>
<img src="thumbnail_2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Thanks heaps.

Comment: I think the answers so far are addressing `class` but the OP is actually talking about the name in the `img src` based on the output they have given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the other solutions, I prefer the following (personal taste)

```
$('div.thumbnail').prepend(function (index) {
    index = '000' + (index + 1);
    return '<span class=index>' + index.substr(index.length - 3) + '</span>';
});
```

The `prepend` method takes a function that should return the html/DOM object that is to be prepended. See more in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

**Edit**: As Michael Durrant commented, you might be wanting the numbers in the `img`'s `src` attribute, not sequential numbers. If that is the case, the following should have you covered.

```
$('div.thumbnail > img').before(function () {
    var index = this.src.match(/\d+/);
    if (index === null) return;
    index = '000' + index;
    return '<span class=index>' + index.substr(index.length - 3) + '</span>';
});
```

Here, we add the span `before` the `img` elements. See the [`before` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/before/) for more.

Comment: see my comment on the q above.

Comment: This is the easiest to understand. I'm trying to make it myself as well. What is `index.substr`?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, That might be what the OP wants, but if it is, I'll wait for the OP to comment on this. @uriah, When I call `index.substr`, `index` is a string. And `substr` is a string method used to get a substring, first argument is start index and second is end index (option, defaults to end of string).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.thumbnail').each(function(i) {
    var num = zeroPad(i + 1, 3);
    $(this).prepend($('<span/>', {
        'class': 'index',
        'text': num
    }));
});
```

The [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method iterates over the elements and the callback receives the zero-based index of the element - so there you have your counter. The element itself is available as `this` (or as the second function argument, but you don't really need that). [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) inserts the passed element/string at the beginning of the element.

For a `zeroPad` function, simply search for "pad number javascript" in Google or here on SO and you'll find quite a few functions. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268377/298479) one for example:

```
function zeroPad(num, numZeros) {
    var n = Math.abs(num);
    var zeros = Math.max(0, numZeros - Math.floor(n).toString().length );
    var zeroString = Math.pow(10,zeros).toString().substr(1);
    if( num < 0 ) {
        zeroString = '-' + zeroString;
    }
    return zeroString + n;
}
```

Comment: +1 (though more explanation would be nice). @uriah: Formatting the index into `001`, `002`, etc. is (quite reasonably) left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: ... `<span class="index">1</span><span class="index">2</span>` does not address `img src`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.thumbnail').each(function(index) {
    $('<span/>', {
         'class': 'index',
         text: "%03d".sprintf(index + 1)
    }).prependTo(this);
});
```

Note that it won't add leading zeroes, as is.

I like the JSXT [`String.js`](http://code.google.com/p/jsxt/source/browse/trunk/js/String.js) module which would allow you to write `"%03d".sprintf(index + 1)`

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/SqQcs/1/

**EDIT** code has changed from first attempt - forgot that `$(<tag>, { ... })` syntax only works in the jQuery constructor, and not in the generalised jQuery argument case.

Comment: At least in recent jQuery versions you need `'class'` instead of `className`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant no, jQuery will add it itself

Answer (score 1):

You can select all elements with the thumbnail class, loop over them, and prepend a span to each element containing the index.

```
// Select all elements with class .thumbnail and loop over them
$(".thumbnail").each(function(i, elm) {
   // Prepend a index span to each element
   $(elm).prepend('<span class="index">' + i + '</span>");
});
```

In this case the index will be number will be zero-based. If you like the index to start with 1, you can change the middle row to this: `$(elm).prepend('<span class="index">' + (i + 1) + '</span>");`

Comment: Using `this` is the most common way in `.each()` though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Agreed, however I thought the example would be more obvious this way. Easier to understand.

Comment: Now realized this addresses `class` not `img src`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant what do you mean?

Comment: when I look at the code that the OP put (top) in the question, it seems like they want the `img src` changed, not the `class`

Comment: not 100% clear from the question.  maybe it is the class they want the index_number on.  Still, dynamic classes like that look yucky somewhat

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Sorry I was just trying to indicate it was the next thumbnail.